# docker-compose up not binding ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose  up
```

I am using this command on Amazon Linux.  It does not bind the ports, so I could not connect to the services running inside the container. The same configuration is working on a local development server. Not sure what I am missing.

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-42 ec2-user]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ec6320747ef3        d8bd4345ca7f        "/bin/sh -c 'gulp bu…"   30 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds                           vigilant_jackson
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gulp serve
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app/code
    ports:
      - "8050:8000"
      - "8005:8005"
      - "8888:8888"
```

`npm -v 5.6.0`

`docker -v Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a215d7133c34aa18e3b72b4a21fd0c6136`

Comment: Please provide your docker-compose yml config

Comment: thanks for your reply, just edited the question with the docker-compose yml file.

Comment: Ports field is empty, usually it shows something

Comment: yes, same config and source shows the port on another server. but not showing anything on this server. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: did you try to run 'docker-compose logs' to see if there is any information related to the ports mappings?

Comment: That `docker ps` output does not match that `docker-compose.yml` file; I'd expect to see the container name include `..._web_...` somewhere, and the command doesn't match either.

Comment: maybe it was run without docker-compose. Try 'docker-compose ps' to see if there is anything shown up

Comment: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose logs . shows "Attaching to" and there is no other information.

Comment: docker-compose ps . shows this and looks empty

`Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------`

Comment: try to kill the container "docker kill ec6320747ef3"
and re-run "docker-compose up -d" again
probably initial run was done not properly

Comment: @evgpisarchik I tried killing the instance and launched it again, still the same. Ports not appearing in `docker ps` and  `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the ports are not published?

Use `docker inspect`, I would guess that they are published. If this is the case, then my guess is that as you are on AWS, you are not ssh-ing to the opened port (8050, 8005, 8888 are ports of the AWS linux instance, if I got your question correctly).

Comment: I inspected the container, here is the network settings:  "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "39fbfb3ab81391f09b38cbe5360c95014f0dae2f49dc51f5b2a1dd5075664d05",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},